# Pylons: View latest debug message

Tags: python, debugging, pylons

Is there a way to view the latest debug message instead of having to copy and paste something like "_debug/view/1269848287" to the browser everytime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(On the off-chance that this helps...)

Ubuntu's default Terminal program auto-detects URLs. When my pylons programs burp, I just ctrl-click on the link in the console.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I feel like an idiot now.  In my case, i just discovered that i could right click the link to open in the browser.